# Break while loop when reaching a certain character

Tags: java, file, while-loop

I have a program that reads a **file.** The file will be split into lines with the `nextLine()` method of scanner.

My file looks like this:

```
*#* lalala lalala lalaa lalala lalal la
x,v,m,k  
221312, stringgg, pwd  
...  
*#* baba bababaa babababa
```

I want to go into a while loop when reading `*#*`, then the while should break when reaching the next `*#*`.

How can this be done?

Comment: I want to process the lines, one by one when being inside the while

Comment: What have you tried? Might want to read up on asking questions on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure while should **`break`**? This will cause while to stop entirely. I think `continue` is better option, since it will just skip to next while iteration, i.e. it will skip current line.

```
while(...) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.startsWith("#")) {
        continue; // or break, if you're sure it's what you want
    }
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
/* If I see the string first time I increase the variable n by one. 
*  If I see the string second time again I increase n by one, now 
*  n will be 2, If n is 2 I break the for loop ABC
*/
public static void main(String []args){
    int n = 0;
    String str;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // System.out.println(line);
    int count = line.length();
    // System.out.print(count);
    ABC:
    for(int i=0; i<line.length()-2;i++){
        str =line.substring(i, i+3);
        if(str.equals("*#*")){
            n++;
            System.out.println(n);
            while(n==2){
                break ABC;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```